# Permissions error on Sophos on Ubuntu Studio 16.04

Tags: software-installation

just downloaded Sophos virus detector on Ubuntu Studio 16.04. when running in terminal "savscan /" the program cannot open files where permissions are needed, I get a (Errno is 13) error ...O.K. fine I then run the program as root "sudo savscan /" and I get  this error " savscan: error while loading shared libraries: libcommunicationsimpl.so.O: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" O.K. what does this mean? How do I correct this so I can run my program as root? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install it in the default directory, which would be /opt/sophos-av/. I came across the same issue after trying to install it on a different partition.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response paed808, unfortunately that i where I have sophos... in opt/sophos-av/  When I downloaded the program, it asked me to install it in opt...=(

Answer (score 0):

When you run `savscan /` and you receive the error

```
savscan libcommunicationsimpl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*
```

your installation is in the default directory `/opt/sophos-av` and `/opt` is probably another mounted partition out of root directory.

I have solved this error by uninstalling Sophos:

```
/opt/sophos-av/uninstall.sh
```

and installing it again in directory `/usr/local/share/sophos-av`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131664/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**